# How do I balance equity and tradition in "Holiday" concert repertoire?

Tags: education, choral

I teach music at a public elementary school in the US.  Our population includes a majority of families who celebrate Christmas (both the sacred holy one and the secular, Santa-based one), a significant population of devout Jewish families, a few families who practice Islam, and some who do not celebrate any holidays at all.

Before I began here, there was a long-standing tradition of holding a Holiday Concert in December.  That repertoire included a wide selection of songs celebrating Christmas, solstice, Chanukah, and winter (snowflakes, sleigh rides, etc.), as well as several songs from the Middle East which weren't necessarily associated with any particular holiday.  I wasn't there when it started, but it seems like the idea was to select an inclusive mix of songs so that all families would be able to come and hear their traditions represented in the children's music.  The concerts were a beloved school tradition and always well-received.  There were no complaints about the content to my knowledge.

We now have a new administrator, who takes issue with the fact that a family who celebrates no holidays due to their religious beliefs has asked that we allow their children to opt out of singing songs associated with any holidays.  In this administrator's view, this family is missing out on the curriculum and we are not being inclusive enough from an equity standpoint.  The administrator's solution is to exclude all songs with connection to any holiday, religious or not, so that everyone will be included.  I have been "invited" to a meeting to discuss this in January.

Note that the family in question is fine with this arrangement, has not complained, and has personally thanked me for sharing the repertoire list with them in advance so they can choose which songs they are comfortable with their children singing.

How do I approach this meeting?  I think it's a very important educational opportunity to teach children about all the wonderful music that comes from all our holiday traditions (without preaching or teaching religious doctrines).
I also think it's important to uphold the traditions that are valued by the community, and I think the community would be quite upset if we never mentioned Christmas or Chanukah all December!  I'm also bound to follow the rules, and of course I want everyone to feel welcome at our school.

**What approach can I take to satisfy the equity opinion of the administration and also perform music associated with holidays and religions?**

Comment: I think that as phrased this would be better on [interpersonal.se] or [workplace.se] -  the music-related work has already been done, it would seem

Comment: @AakashM I thought about that, but was hoping to get the viewpoint of music teachers on this...

Comment: Man... as somebody with strong opinions on public education, religion, cultural representation, and curricular programming, I'd love to discuss this, but isn't it kinda opinion-based for any SE? And not really musical at its core—the same issues have plagued the English class for decades, as parents and faculty try to figure out whether their kids can be forced to read *Are You There God? It's Me, Margaret*, or Huck Finn, or even Narnia. Maybe it should be taken up in chat? My quickest, top-of-my-head two cents: ...

Comment: 1) There *are* official guidelines. In my state of NC, and I would guess in most?, it basically says that you can program religious artworks for their artistic and pedagogical merit. Thus, you can put on Vivaldi's *Gloria* without violating separation of church and state, or any cultural artifact of any other religion, as long as you can show its educational benefit (which might be simply enriching kids with knowledge of that culture).

Comment: ... Personally, IMO we're always a bit dishonest with this, aren't we? "Oh yeah, our Christmas concert has 10 sacred Christian works, one song about a dreidel, and a token Kwanzaa song. But yeah, it's all just for objective artistic merit." I mean, we don't actually program some druidic chant about child sacrifice, or some Lovecraftian ritual intended to summon eldritch horrors (and I very well might want my kids to sit them out if we did). It's also true that 2) we can't represent *every* culture. I mean, literally can't; there simply isn't time. (So isn't it important to interrogate...

Comment: To that, Andy, no one is being forced to do anything here, and I know it's legal to program this music in my state.  The crux of the issue for me is how to respond to the "if one student can't celebrate this, no one should" mentality.  Maybe that is better to appear in chat, or on another SE site.

Comment: Good point about not being able to program everything, Andy.  I shoot for programming something from as many of the traditions I know of that have meaning to our families.i have half a mind to just let the admin cancel the whole thing and let it be their idea and let THEM deal with the angry parents!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132568/discussion-between-nuggethead-and-andy-bonner).

Comment: I see a contradiction between "The administrator's solution is to exclude all songs with connection to any holiday, religious or not, so that everyone will be included." and "What approach can I take to satisfy the equity opinion of the administration and also perform music associated with holidays and religions?" At this point, one of them has to fall by the wayside, and unless you can convince administration, I'm afraid it's the latter.

Comment: If it were I, I would just get on board with a winter concert that has nothing to do with the holidays. Or at the least do what I’m told to do by my superiors. There are so many places where holiday music is not optional - TV, stores, even apartment building lobbies. There’s a certain kind of joy in a winter concert where one doesn’t have to be afraid of “The Little Drummer Boy”. Side note: I’m reminded of the satire of the secular winter show depicted in South Park, with minimalist score by Phillip Glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cancel the Holidays concert while your boss thinks this way.  You can’t win.  Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably the most accurate answer.... And the most likely outcome